# How to make a click hide after certain condition (Angular 4+)?

Tags: html, angular

I have a click button that is suppose to hide after certain amount of inputs.
I would like it to hide once it reaches a limit, but currently what is doing that it would only hide when it's clicked again. Which is a bad user experience.

```
private isAddUserVisible = true;
```

```
public limitedAmount() {
    this.isAddUserVisible =
      this.userL.length + this.service.getTotalLength() < this.userService.getTotalValue();
    if (this.isAddUserVisible) {
      this.userL.push(this.create());
    }
  }
```

```
<div class="add-icon-button medium-3 columns" *ngIf="this.isAddUserVisible" (click)="limitedAmount()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, we don't have the whole picture but try manually calling change detection.

Inject `constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef)`

and then call: `this.ref.detectChanges();` where appropiate

Read more about it  [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)